# Intellij IDEA Ultimate Edition - Locally Installed Target JVM Versions not showing past JDK 17

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea

On macOS Monterey 12.6.5 am running the following version of IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition:

[image]

The following JDKs are installed in my local machine:

[image]

These are visible via IntelliJ:

[image]

However, the Target JVM version dialog only shows up until JDK 17?

[image]

Does the version of IntelliJ IDEA support `JVM versions > 17`?

If so, how can it be configured to show these versions in that `Target JVM version` drop down list?

Comment: Just a wild guess… when desperately trying to fix bizarre behavior in IntelliJ, I eventually resort to [invalidate caches](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/invalidate-caches.html) and a reboot of computer.

Comment: I was trying to reproduce this on the community edition but the new project screen looks completely different to what you have. What steps did you take to get there, especially what type of project are you creating? Perhaps I won't be able to help if the versions are different, I'm on linux too.